# Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection - Manage 1111 Errors In System Log

Tags: remote-desktop, redirection, printer

I have a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit machine that acts as a host for several remote Windows 7 Pro machines that connect to the host machine using the Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection client that ships with Windows 7 Pro. I have enabled printer redirection for the remote machines and it's working perfectly.  HOWEVER, every time a remote machine connects with RDC, those printers installed on the remote machine that don't have a matching printer driver installed in the host machine's Print Management sub-system generate a 1111 Error in the host machine's System log.  This is a GIANT PITA because these messages are generated EVERY time a remote machine connects to the host machine using RDC!  The 1111 Error messages are really beginning to pile up.  I'm worried about filling up the System log on the host machine with useless error messages.

Has anyone found a way to deal with this problem besides, 1.) Disabling printer redirection - which I can't do, or 2.) Installing printer drivers for every printer installed on every remote machine that connects to the host machine?  This seems like something that Microsoft would have fixed LONG ago, but I can't find ANY solution.

Comment: Microsoft did fix the problem long ago, beginning with Windows Server 2008. Windows 7 isn't a server operating system and isn't intended to be used as such. Use the right tool (OS) for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Windows 7 isn't a server operating system.
2. What do you mean by this statement: `This seems like something that Microsoft would have fixed LONG ago, but I can't find ANY solution`? Generating an event log entry is a problem? Would you rather that Windows not log any warning or error events? Would it be better if Windows ignored all warning and error events? You're misusing the product, getting a warning/error in the event log and somehow your opinion is that this is something that's a problem on the vendor side of the equation? I don't understand that line of thinking.
3. You're most probably in violation of the Windows 7 EULA.
4. Your statement about hosting several Windows 7 machines on a Windows 7 machine and the RDP clients connecting to the host machine makes no sense to me. How are you "hosting" these Windows 7 machines on the Windows 7 machine and why would the RDP clients be connecting to the host machine rather than the hosted machines?
5. Use a server operating system for server duties, like hosting virtual machines, etc. This "problem" (as you seem to think) is easily resolved with Windows Server 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 or 2012 R2.
6. Stop pointing the finger at the vendor when you create your own problem.

Some of this answer may come across as a bit harsh but I really don't like to hear people blaming the vendor when they're clearly and obviously using the product outside of the scope of design, intention, functionality and licensing of the product in question.

Comment: I failed to mention that the "hosted Windows machines" are VMware Player machines.  BTW - I am in compliance with the EULA - I've purchased Windows 7 Pro licenses for each of the VMs as well as all of the applications that run in each VM.  I need this configuration for about 4 months to conduct a research project that involves remote users, then it gets taken down.  So I'm trying to understand if there's a solution to the build-up of 1111 Errors I'm getting so that my System log doesn't fill up.  My bad for not including the info on the VMs.

Comment: The events are related to printer driver redirection (as you've already stated) and the problem is that Windows 7 has no mechanism to "load" the correct printer driver on the guests. This problem has been solved in Windows Server operating systems beginning with Windows Server 2008 with the use of the `Terminal Services Easy Print` and in earlier versions of Windows Server with the `Terminal Server Fallback Printer Driver` or with the use of a custom print.inf file. On Windows 7 the solution would be to install the correct printer driver for each redirected printer on the appropriate guest.

Comment: So you'll either need to install the correct printer driver, find a suitable third party solution, or live with the events being generated.

Comment: Additionally, the default settings for the Event logs on standalone Windows 7 machines (not joined to an Active Directory domain) is to overwrite events as needed, so you're in no danger of the Event logs "filling up".

Comment: Thanks for the response about the stand-alone Win7 logs.  I didn't know that.  I won't have to worry about that now.